# Recognise pattern from a string using php

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

let's say i have a string like this:

`$string = 'Lorem Ipsum available, <a href="##article-6##">but the majority</a> have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour.';`

Notice the `<a href="##article-6##">but the majority</a>`

Using this i want to link my articles based on their id's from the database.

Now, how can a perform a preg_replace on that string to see if i have something like `##article-6##` and extract only that number?

Is this idea a good one? Can i do it in a better way?

EDIT:

I did it like this:

```
$post_content = preg_replace_callback('/##article-(\d+)##/', function($matches){$args = explode(',', $matches[1]); // separate the arguments
return call_user_func_array('article_seo_url', $args); /* pass the arguments to article_seo_url function*/ }, $post_content);
```

Using this code i can also replace multiple url's

Comment: Why not do the direct link when create the string?

Comment: please escape your inner quotes.

Comment: I want to do that to be sure i always have the link to the correct url in case i change the structure of the url's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do a `preg_replace`, you'd want to use a regex such as `/##article-(\d+)##/` and do something like this:

```
$string = 'Lorem Ipsum available, <a href="##article-6##">but the majority</a> have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour.';
$string = preg_replace('/##article-(\d+)##/', 'link/to/article/with/id/$1.html', $string);
```

would result in $string being:

```
Lorem Ipsum available, <a href="link/to/article/with/id/6.html">but the majority</a> have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour.
```

Comment: yes. that outputs what you've said but if i use `$string = preg_replace('/##article-(\d+)##/', article_seo_url($1), $string);` it doesn't work.                                                                       I get this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in...`

Comment: even i didn't used exactly your code i accepted your answer because it is the most similar with the final code i used.

Answer (score 0):

If the ID is always 3 digits you don't even need regex.

```
$string = 'Lorem Ipsum available, <a href="##article-6##">but the majority</a> have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour.';
$start = strpos($string, 'article-');
$articleId = substr ( $string , intval($start)+8 , 3 );
```

Comment: Yeah, copying and pasting is bad. Sorry about that.

Comment: first you forgot `;`. second: this code shows me a error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function int() in...`

Comment: Fixed, sorry I don't use those functions often, was off the top of my head.

Comment: ... okay do the math then. I told you I don't use these functions often. instead of +1 make it +8

Answer (score 0):

If your href is stored in a variable like so:

```
$href="http://www.domain.com";
```

You can just insert that directly into the string, like so:

```
$string = "Lorem Ipsum available, <a href=\"$href\">but the majority</a> have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour.";
```

Please note that it is important you either escape your literal quotes or use a different kind, in this case singles.

Comment: No, that string is extracted from the database. In that way i want to link another articles based on their id. I want to do that to be sure i always have the link to the correct url in case i change the structure of the url's. I thought is a good idea to do that.

Comment: In that case, please try Rick Calder's solution